# MongoDB - How to find and append / find and upsert both document and fields

Tags: java, mongodb, updates

In Mongo, is there a built-in way to update a document and instead of replacing all contents of the query document, to update those nodes which are the same and append those which do not exist in the original document.

For example, imagine I insert the following document into my collection:

```
{
  "name" : "Goku",
  "level" : 9000
}
```

Now, at some later point, I wish to update my existing document with the following document I received:

```
{
  "name" : "Goku",
  "son" : "Gohan"
}
```

Ideally, I would like a way to perform an update and produce the following document:

```
{
  "name" : "Goku",
  "level" : 9000,
  "son" : "Gohan"
}
```

The standard case is to overwrite the existing document with the new document (as it should be). However, is there a built-in or clever way to achieve the result above without first finding the first document, appending onto it, and then performing an update?

Thanks.

-- EDIT --

@pennstatephil has the correct answer below. Just in case anyone's is helped by this, here's an implementation of this example in Java as of driver version 2.12.0:

```
String json = "{'name' : 'Goku', 'level' : 9000 }";
DBObject document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$set", document);
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("name", document.get("name"));
collection.findAndModify(query, null, null, false, update, false, true);

json = "{'name' : 'Goku', 'son' : 'Gohan'}";
document = (DBObject) JSON.parse(json);
update = new BasicDBObject("$set", document);
query = new BasicDBObject().append("name", document.get("name"));
collection.findAndModify(query, null, null, false, update, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) and `$set` (on the `update` clause) is what you're looking for.